# href mailto with outlook signature

Tags: html, email, outlook

I don't think that this is possible, but I figured I would reach out to you guys to see if anyone knows anything.

This is my href... but when I decide to add a body to it, it doesn't place the outlook signature with the link. This link is being sent through email, so I don't have the ability to use Javascript or anything. From what I have been reading it seems that if there is no delay between creating the email and adding a subject then Outlook does not include the signature.

```
href="mailto:xyz@12345.com?Subject=TSC%20Pricing&amp;body=Hi,%0D%0A%0D%0ACan you please send me pricing for TSC Printers."
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Am guessing it's a limitation in the client. Facing this dilemma at the moment, and will probably just not add the Body (because for me, it's better that the signature of the user stays that the body gets auto-added).

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem - Apparntly it's because your predefining the body of the e-mail which removes the signature. I have heard that if you put a delay between the subject and the body it will appear.

Maybe put the body into cvlipboard and paste it after it loads - have no idea how to accomplish this though.

I hope this helps